# ranges and conditional formatting on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to apply a conditional formatting on a range of cells (more rows and more columns).
The condition must be a compare among the value contained in the cells and the value of another range (single column).

An example in the spreadsheet linked below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aS9iLkPycb0ABfv3pk8HX9JVS2SmdTJ76Bd5KO_P-gI/edit?usp=sharing

I have done it with a conditional formatting rule for each column (n columns => n rules).

I have use a custom formula like this:

```
=A:A>F:F
```

it compare the value of the cell #i of the column A with the value of the cell #i of the column F.

I tried to write a single formula that cover all the condition without a positive result.

exist a method to do it with one single rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try selecting range A2:E13 from your example and using this formula:

```
=A:A>$G:$G
```

Dollar sign $ freezes column G:G → $G:$G, and each cell from range is compared with cell from column G